# How to pass data from filter to action?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Let's suppose this filter:

```
public function execute ($filterChain)
{
    if ($this->isFirstCall())
    {
        $loggeduser = array();
        .
        .
        .
        $this->getContext()->getResponse()->setSlot ('loggeduser', $loggeduser);
    }
}
```

I want to pass this loggeduser array to every action, even to ajax actions. This variable stores the logged user informations. the `get_slot();` function doesn't work. How to solve this? Session must not be used this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`$this->getContext()->getRequest()->setParameter('loggeduser', $loggeduser);`

Comment: You can also store it in session: `$this->getContext()->getUser()->setAttribute('loggeduser', $loggeduser)`

Comment: He said "session must not be used this time."

Comment: looks OK, but im not convinced that a general data should travel among "request parameters".

Comment: You can also store that in some user property. Something like `$this->getContext()->getUser()->blabla = $loggeduser;`. And get it in actions with something like `$this->getUser()->blabla`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getSlot()` method on the `sfWebResponse` but there is `getSlots()` so you can retrieve an array of all the slots you have passed to the response.

In any controller:

```
$slots = $this->getResponse()->getSlots();
print_r($slots['loggeduser']);
```

As [@Vlad Jula-Nedelcu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666096/vlad-jula-nedelcu) stated, if you don't want use the session and really need to only pass a variable between controllers in one script run you can set a property on any object kept in the sfContext.

Unfortunately in Sf 1.4. you're not able to add your own objects to the sfContext, you have to use the ones which are already there.